# I created a DOM event that isn't giving me the result I wanted

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I created a function to change the color value of my elements. I used the same function on both elements with different events but my second element isn't changing only the first element.

```
function colorChange(event){
  let randomColor = 'rgb(' + colorValue() + ',' + colorValue() + ',' + colorValue() + ')';
  button.style.backgroundColor = randomColor
}

button.addEventListener('click', colorChange);
mysteryButton.onwheel = colorChange;
```

Comment: Whats button in this context? If you could share it in a sandbox env, that would help a lot o/

Comment: And how are you querying the button element? There is not enough information in your question to solve without guessing at how button is being defined and how many button elements there may be as it seems t o me there are more than one and you do not have a loop set up that would iterate over a nodeList or HTML collection.

Comment: How do you reference `mysteryButton` element? Is it correctly referenced? Can you integrate your code example with the `html` code and the code where you reference the elements in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should try instead

```js
function colorChange(event){
  let randomColor = 'rgb(' + colorValue() + ',' + colorValue() + ',' + colorValue() + ')';
  event.target.style.backgroundColor = randomColor
}

button.addEventListener('click', colorChange);
mysteryButton.onwheel = colorChange;
```